# Removing object inside function

Tags: c++, function, object, delete-operator

Which code is good(if it is good)

```
void DeleteObject(Object* obj)
{
    delete obj;
}
```

or

```
void DeleteObject(Object** obj)  
{  
    delete *obj;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    Object *obj = new Object();  
    DeleteObject(&obj); or DeleteObject(obj);  
}
```

In fact `DeleteObject` function is not so short(it deletes objects fields).

Comment: You won't have this problem if you use smart pointers.

Comment: Or if you delete the fields in a destructor

Comment: @Soohjun: Who cares? The question is about C++. Other languages are irrelevant.

Comment: @DeadMG Obvious troll apparently wasn't so obvious.

Comment: of course...DeleteObject(obj);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion neither.

The person creating the object should be responsible for the object and thus delete it.

So my answer is that `main` should do the `delete`.

Comment: By extension, the `Object::~Object` should delete any pointers that are held by `Object`.

Comment: Nobody should `delete` anything. You should alway use smart pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG - Snart pointers do have an overhead that may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

This is good:

```
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
    std::auto_ptr<Object> ptr = new Object();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `auto_ptr` be avoided when possible? Either boost or C++11 `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` would be preferred if available.

Comment: @Joe: true, but I'm keeping it simple here.

Comment: The others are still pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend to use a smart pointer as suggested by @nightcracker, but if you really don't want that I recommend a reference to the pointer:

```
void DeleteObject(Object* &obj)
{
    delete obj;
    obj = NULL;
}
```

This ensures that the original pointer is set to null, so, you cannot accidentally access the object any more and a reference is safer than pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You say: "The function deletes object fields" which only means that something much more horrible is going on here. A class should be responsible for managing its own resources (sub-objects) in its destructor and constructors. If managing some sub-objects through the outside is required provide a public API to manage them. In any way, don't use raw-pointers to manage life-time, but use a smart-pointer (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`). There are of course some edge cases, but given that you are asking a question like this I don't think you have one on your hands.

Comment: it deletes char arrays, just simple `delete [] char_array;`

Comment: @user1112008 What is the difference? It is horribly messy. Free functions are great, but never use them when the state of something is truly internal. Nothing outside of your class should be concerned with the allocation or deallocation of an internal resource. At some point you might switch to `vector`, `deque` or something very fancy.